# Preventing multiple includes in C++

Tags: c++, header, header-files

i have 2 classes in different namespaces and both of them needs to include same Image.h class but when i include at the same time i get an error. Here my classes:

FilterManager.h:

```
#ifndef FILTERMANAGER_H_
#define FILTERMANAGER_H_

#include "../Images/Image.h"
namespace Filter {

class FilterManager {
public:
    Image* applyFilter(int filterType, PGMImage *pgmImage);

};

} /* namespace Filter */
#endif /* FILTERMANAGER_H_ */
```

Main Application class : This includes Images/Image.h and Filter/FilterManager.h at the same time and i get an error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Images/Image.h"
#include "Filter/FilterManager.h"


using namespace std;

int main() {

    //new typename ImageIO::ImageIO;

    Images::Image *Image = NULL;

    Filter::FilterManager::getInstance();

    pgmImage = imageIO->readPGM("Resources/house.256.pgm");

    return 0;
}
```

And Image.h class

```
#ifndef IMAGE_H_
#define IMAGE_H_

#include "Image.h"



namespace Images {

class Image {
public:
    Image();
    virtual ~Image();


private:
    int** imatrix(int nrl,int nrh,int ncl,int nch);
};

} /* namespace Image */
#endif /* IMAGE_H_ */
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Uh... what error? And how is inside Image.h?

Comment: Can you show the code of Image.h? Does it use `#ifndef IMAGE`? What type of error it is?

Comment: @cagryInside: You still didn't provide the error.

Comment: FWIW, "FilterManager.h" should only forward-declare `Image::Image` -- it does not need to include "Image.h". This doesn't _explain_ your problem (whatever your problem is), but it does get rid of it by improving your code in other ways.

Comment: Uhm still error is missing, would be helpful.

Comment: I guess the problem is inside "PGMImage.h". You need to narrow down the issue quite considerably before this question contains a _minimal_ testcase. I'm bowing out of this one.

Comment: My error /Filter/FilterManager.h:18:2: error: 'Image' does not name a type

Comment: I don't see any #include "PGMImage.h" Where is it? And what is PGMImage?

Comment: its not important. i delete some includes to post shorter question

Comment: I don't see any error now. Probably the error is elsewhere. I hope PGMImage does not inherits from Image :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class FilterManager {
public:
   Images::Image* applyFilter(int filterType, PGMImage *pgmImage);
};
```

You forgot the namespace.

I don't see any #include "PGMImage.h"
Where is it? And what is PGMImage?

Why in Image.h there is an include to Image.h?

Comment: I have done this but i still get an error and PGMImage comes from somewhere else not inherits from image

Comment: What error do you get now?  I'm pretty sure it won't be "'Image' does not name a type" anymore.

Comment: Why in Image.h there is an include to Image.h?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have a problem with multiple includes but with namespaces, try returning `Images::Image` from the `applyFilter` method.

Comment: @cagryInside: that is however exactly what your error is pointing to, make sure you have no other references to `Image` without specifying the namespace. Also, take a note of Tomalak's comment, it's a very good hint.